# Cassandra Java Driver Cold to Hot in 500ms?

Tags: java, cassandra

I experience a cold to hot (first use) of cluster and session to a local data source (Cassandra) to take 640ms. Any additional connect takes 80 to 100ms so the overhead of the first connect is about 500+ms. Is that normal and is there anything I can do to get this figure down somehow? I use a T410 (i5 2.5GHz).

[Update]

```
23:27:11.453 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.SystemProperties - com.datastax.driver.NEW_NODE_DELAY_SECONDS is undefined, using default value 1
23:27:11.460 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.SystemProperties - com.datastax.driver.NON_BLOCKING_EXECUTOR_SIZE is undefined, using default value 4
23:27:11.463 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.SystemProperties - com.datastax.driver.NOTIF_LOCK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS is undefined, using default value 60
23:27:11.607 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Starting new cluster with contact points [localhost/127.0.0.1:9042]
23:27:11.905 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Transport initialized and ready
23:27:11.906 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
23:27:11.969 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing schema
23:27:12.016 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
23:27:12.051 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Successfully connected to localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
23:27:12.052 [main] INFO  c.d.d.c.p.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy - Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
23:27:12.053 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - New Cassandra host localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 added
23:27:12.076 [Cassandra Java Driver worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] Transport initialized and ready
23:27:12.077 [Cassandra Java Driver worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Session - Added connection pool for localhost/127.0.0.1:9042
23:27:12.097 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=true] closing connection
23:27:12.103 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Shutting down
23:27:12.105 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[localhost/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=true] closing connection
23:27:12.123 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Starting new cluster with contact points [/127.0.0.1:9042]
23:27:12.132 [main] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[/127.0.0.1:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Transport initialized and ready
23:27:12.132 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
23:27:12.138 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing schema
23:27:12.168 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
23:27:12.192 [main] DEBUG c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection - [Control connection] Successfully connected to /127.0.0.1:9042
23:27:12.192 [main] INFO  c.d.d.c.p.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy - Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
23:27:12.192 [main] INFO  com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:9042 added
23:27:12.201 [Cassandra Java Driver worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Connection - Connection[/127.0.0.1:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] Transport initialized and ready
23:27:12.202 [Cassandra Java Driver worker-0] DEBUG com.datastax.driver.core.Session - Added connection pool for /127.0.0.1:9042
```

As one can see the first connection attempt uses up to 600ms and more depending how one might read the figures.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is this has to do with connection initialization.   In all currently released versions of the java driver connections are initialized 1 after another synchronously.  Fortunately, individual host pools are initialized in parallel, but the connections are not.  If you are using 2.0.9, which has a default # of core connections of 8 that could explain why you are seeing slow initialization times.  Also if you are using password authentication, that will slow things down quite a bit as well (from ~0-10ms per connection to ~60-120ms).

In java driver 2.0.10, which will be released soon, all connections are initialized in parallel which greatly improves Session initialization.  For information see [JAVA-701](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-701).

Comment: I use the java driver 2.1.5 and Cassandra 2.1.4. Is there any setting I might be able to tweak?

Comment: Hrm, might be something you can do.  How many cassandra nodes are you connecting to?  Are you using authentication?  How many CPU cores do you have?  (cores affects size of thread pool for initializing connections)

Comment: No compression no encryption no authentication. Its a single local instance for testing purposes and waiting 600ms every time I run some tests is something I would like to cut down since the test will run at least every two minutes.

Comment: Can you bump up the logging level of com.datastax.driver.core to DEBUG?  That may give some clarity as to why it may be taking so long.

Comment: I added the log entries. The Cassandra instance was already warmed up so the timing is really related to the client side of the story.